# Plone Folder Restrictions

Tags: directory, admin, plone, restrictions

In Plone, I created a new folder called "Admin" that appears at the top navigation bar.  How do I restrict access to this folder so only site administrators will have access to this folder? (and, preferably, only those admins would see that link appear)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a folder at the root level and keep it private and don't share it with any other groups. Administrators (by default) can view all content. Items for which a user does not have permission are not visible in the Global Nav, Nav portlets, search, etc.

Comment: This led me to more searching around on how to great groups and add users to groups.  However in the end, it was editing the sharing properties that gave me what I was searching for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the sharing tab and add the users/groups needed.